# How to get Android users to share my app on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook-share

I want to offer people access to some premium part of the app in exchange for them sharing the app on Facebook.

Is there a good tutorial for that which does not require me to integrate the FB SDK?

Any code samples for how to do this would be very appreciated!

Comment: You can add a share button or menu item. When clicked you can use Intent to share your application's Play Store URL or website link. It will show all messaging apps,  mail clients and Facebook to share the link.

Comment: @ArnabJain Thanks, but how do I verify that they actually shared?

Comment: Well you can add extra text to Intent with @yourFbUsername so that when user shares the link you get a notification that user x mentioned you in his/her post. But this is not the best way to do it. You will have to manually confirm that the user shared the link.

Comment: No, but the app has to verify that the share happened. Only if the share happened, then user gets the premium content.

Comment: Am sorry it's not something I can help you with. May be Intent has some sort of return value according to user action. Say 0 is returned when no app is clicked and 1 is returned when an app is clicked from the share menu. Just a speculation.

Comment: There's no straight forward way. You will have to explore Facebook API to see how to get notified on your server side when someone mentioned you. Then your server can notify your application.

Comment: See this. May be can be of help. http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/02/share-with-intents.html?m%3D1&ei=zoc3Fqtf&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=853&ts=1453859086&sig=ALL1Aj4eXH0kEhA-jW7zg_6YNd1QyyRWJw